# get list of server subfolders

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to give jquery a path and it would return list of all subfolders in given path?

I have this, which returns all pics from the folder:

```
var folder = "photos/";
          $.ajax({
              url : folder,
              success: function (data) {
                  $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                      if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                          $('#links').append(
                            '<a href="' + folder + val + '" title="' + val + '">' +
                            '<img src="' + folder + val +'" class="photos"></a>'
                            );
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
```

Just need proper regexp for "ends with /"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to give jquery a path and it would return list of all subfolders in given path?

Every webserver will return this information in a different format, and some will not return such information at all.

> Just need proper regexp for "ends with /"

Ah, OK. Replace `val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)` with `val.match(/\/$/)` and then it will look for a trailing `/` character.

`$` represents end of string. `\/` is an escaped `/` character because `/` normally represents the beginning and end of the regex.

I think if you used [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag and title you may have gotten this answer more quickly. :-)

Comment: Deleted my answer and choosing yours, your regex is more simple. Also thanks for the point that the information returned may vary per server - I'm lucky then :)